# Can I delete macOS Partition from Boot Camp and then load a new macOS?

Tags: macos, windows, bootcamp, partition, startup

On my Mac, I can only access Boot Camp and not macOS. It keeps on restarting, when I’m trying to access macOS.

I can’t also load Recovery, Internet Recovery and it fails to boot from from USB. It keeps on restarting.

I’ve tried all boot key’s combinations and none of them work.

Is it possible or rather will it work, if I delete the Mac partition from Windows (Boot Camp) and then load a new macOS?

Answer (score 0):

Highly unlikely. Windows doesn't really know how the macOS side works at all.

You would be in the same place as you are now, but have only Internet Recovery or a boot USB to fall back on, with a risk [depending on the precise way Boot Camp was installed] of harming the Windows setup too.

You should instead investigate the true cause of the boot fail on the Mac side.